# How do I add a string to a ASP.NET global resource that only belongs to one language?

Tags: asp.net, localization

I have a global resources file for different languages:

```
Resource.resx
Resource.de-DE.resx
Resource.ro-RO.resx
```

For the most part, all the strings in `Resource.resx` have localized versions in other languages as well.

However, I have certain strings that should only exist in `Resource.de-DE.resx` but not `Resource.resx`. When I try to use them in my code:

```
GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource", "Personal Identification Number")
```

I get an error that says **Cannot resolve resource item 'Personal Identification Number'**. The string still gets localized properly when I view the page in German because it's present in `Resource.de-DE.resx`, but because it's not in `Resource.resx`, I get this error in Visual Studio, and I'd like to get rid of the error.

How do I work around this so that I don't get this error message? Should I move the local-specific string to another resource file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole resource fallback approach really assumes that all strings are present for the base language.

I imagine you have this scenario because you implemented some feature that only applies to German and you don't want to add unnecessary resources to your base language as these will increase the localization effort for languages that don't need it.

One solution would be to create a separate local resource file. And either only translate this one into German (and not other languages) or make it a base resource (without the `de-DE`  language code but still with your German strings in it).

Another solution (if you can't create a local resource file and for some reason can only use global resources) would be to add those extra entries to your base global resources (`Resource.resx`) and make it obvious that you don't want these translated. For example make them all blank strings and use the Comment field to explain that these strings are for German only. Not very nice.

Answer (score 0):

I just replicated your scenario and it works fine.  just create another resource file containing local-specific strings. hope this helps :)

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say.